# With Bash, How do I find all directories with two directories and move them to a copied tree structure?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory

Lets say that I have the following directory tree structure:

```
./Original
  ├── Dir1
  │   ├── Objects
  │   └── Textures
  ├── Dir2
  │   ├── SubDir1
  │   │   └── SubSubDir1
  │   │       ├── Objects
  │   │       └── Textures
  │   └── SubDir2
  │       ├── Objects
  │       └── Textures
  └── Dir3
      ├── Objects
      ├── SubDir1
      │   ├── Objects
      │   └── Textures
      └── Textures
```

And I also have a similar structure (it is actually a copy of the Original Directory without the Objects and Textures directories:

```
./Copy
  ├── Dir1
  ├── Dir2
  │   ├── SubDir1
  │   │   └── SubSubDir1
  │   └── SubDir2
  └── Dir3
      └── SubDir1
```

How do I move all of the Objects and Textures directories and their files from the original to the corresponding position in the Copy Directory? It should look like this when complete:

```
./Original
  ├── Dir1
  ├── Dir2
  │   ├── SubDir1
  │   │   └── SubSubDir1
  │   └── SubDir2
  └── Dir3
      └── SubDir1

./Copy
  ├── Dir1
  │   ├── Objects
  │   └── Textures
  ├── Dir2
  │   ├── SubDir1
  │   │   └── SubSubDir1
  │   │       ├── Objects
  │   │       └── Textures
  │   └── SubDir2
  │       ├── Objects
  │       └── Textures
  └── Dir3
      ├── Objects
      ├── SubDir1
      │   ├── Objects
      │   └── Textures
      └── Textures
```

Things to notice:

- Not all directories in the Original Directory has Objects and Textures directories
- The Objects and Textures Directories are moved and not copied
- Also the Original and Copy directories are in the same directory and this is where the command/function should be called

Please use this command to build the starting structure:

```
mkdir -p Original/Dir1/Objects Original/Dir1/Textures Original/Dir2/SubDir1/SubSubDir1/Objects Original/Dir2/SubDir1/SubSubDir1/Textures Original/Dir2/SubDir2/Objects Original/Dir2/SubDir2/Textures Original/Dir3/Objects Original/Dir3/Textures Original/Dir3/SubDir1/Objects Original/Dir3/SubDir1/Textures
mkdir -p Copy/Dir1 Copy/Dir2/SubDir1/SubSubDir1 Copy/Dir2/SubDir2 Copy/Dir3/SubDir1
```

Comment: I can not really understand what you want exactly. either use find or rsync.

Comment: An assignment for sure, so tell me what have you tried so far?

Comment: It's not an assignment.  I'm messing Aaron's with my files as bash

Comment: Autocorrect - I'm messing around with my files and bash.

Comment: @George I gave you the mkdir so you can build a test environment for yourself.  My actual directories are not nabbed Dir and SubDir

Comment: Well people do not like it (or at least I don't) when you obscure information by using foo and bar or $some_variable rather than the actual directories. I tend to answer with `run $some_command on your $DIRECTORIES`

Comment: The point is that the directory name doesn't matter.  That way if someone wants to use it they don't have to change much

Comment: there is a flaw in your description I think - `Dir2` has two directories, but neither of them are the ones you want to move. Can we use the names `Objects` and `Textures` instead of the fact that there are two directories? Or do you want to move directories with no subdirectories?

Comment: No the Copy directory is already made.  Just think of it as it was copied before the Objects and Textures were added.  Then once those added I want to have them moved to the Copy.

Comment: You wants to copy folders, but move files. Is it?

Comment: @Redbob the `Textures` and `Objects` are directories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simulation. Once you've run it and you're sure everything's correct, remove `echo` and run it again:

```
shopt -s globstar
for d in **/{Objects,Textures}; do
    echo mv "$d" "Copy/${d##Original/}"
done
```

Explanation:

- Turning on the Bash option "globstar" makes the glob `**/` match zero or more subdirectories.
- Bash expands `**/{Objects,Textures}` to `**/Objects **/Textures`.
- `${d##Original/}` means "remove the string `Original/` from the start of `$d`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update directory trees using another location, the best tool is `rsync`, the the second-best possibly `tar`. Writing a shell script is often overkill:

```
rsync -aP --ignore-existing Original/ Copy
```

The options:

- `-a` tells `rsync` to retain ownerships, modes, etc.
- `-P` prints progress information
- `--ignore-existing` means that files already in `Copy` won't be touched.
- The trailing `/` after `Original` tells `rsync` to copy the contents of `Original` to `Copy`, instead of copying `Original` itself.

Delete `Original` when done, or use the `--remove-source-files` files option to have `rsync` delete files when it's done copying them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could manage to move **directories with no subdirectories**.

First turn on recursive globbing:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Now you can glob recursively with `**`. You can turn it off with `shopt -u globstar`, but it will be off anyway next time you open a shell.

Now in the parent directory of both `Copy` and `Original`:

```
for d in Original/**/; do $(ls -lAq "$d" | grep -q '^d') || echo mv -vn -- "$d" Copy"${d/Original/}"; done
```

Remove `echo` after testing to actually move the directories (and their contents of course - `mv` doesn't have an `-r` flag)

Let's make that a bit more readable

```
shopt -s globstar
for d in Original/**/; do 
    $(ls -lAq "$d" | grep -q '^d') || 
    echo mv -vn -- "$d" Copy"${d/Original/}"
done
```

Wait, did I just [parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)? Uh, yes, I did. But I think it's alright(!) since I think I can rely on the output's consistency in this case. No matter what characters a filename contains, the output of `ls -l` on the directory where that file resides will begin with a string that defines its type and permissions. In `ls -l` all directory listings begin with a `d`, eg

```
drwxrwxr-x 26 zanna zanna 4096 Oct  5 19:57 playground
```

Even newlines don't mess this up, as they are displayed as `?` (even after piping) if we add `-q`.

```
$(ls -lAq "$d" | grep -q '^d')
```

checks that the directory has some subdirectories. Instead of collecting output from `grep`, we collect the exit status. If the command is successful, we do nothing, but if it fails, we `mv` the directory (using the `||` or operator, which means, if the command before `||` fails, do the one after it).

We use string manipulation to remove `Original` so the directories are copied to the right places in `Copy`.

Here's the result:

```
$ tree
.
├── Copy
│   ├── Dir1
│   │   ├── Objects
│   │   └── Textures
│   ├── Dir2
│   │   ├── SubDir1
│   │   │   └── SubSubDir1
│   │   │       ├── Objects
│   │   │       └── Textures
│   │   └── SubDir2
│   │       ├── Objects
│   │       └── Textures
│   └── Dir3
│       ├── Objects
│       ├── SubDir1
│       │   ├── Objects
│       │   └── Textures
│       └── Textures
└── Original
    ├── Dir1
    ├── Dir2
    │   ├── SubDir1
    │   │   └── SubSubDir1
    │   └── SubDir2
    └── Dir3
        └── SubDir1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how this might work for you. Please note that this script is to be run at the same level with the original and copy directories and also that it probably needs adaptation to your actual needs. Good Luck.

```
#!/bin/bash

src="original" 
dst="./copy"

function findLocation {
    for i in `find $src/ -type d -name "$1"`; do
        IFS='/' read -ra directories <<< "$i"
        dirNum=${#directories[@]}
        let "arrayNum=$dirNum-2"

        arrs=()

        for ((k=1 ; k<=$arrayNum; k++)); do
            arrs+=("${directories[$k]}")
        done

        echo "===============================++++++++++++++++"

        function join {
            local IFS="$1"
            shift
            echo "$*"
        }

        constructDst=`join / ${arrs[@]}`
        destination="$dst/$constructDst/"

        if [ ! -d $destination ] ; then
            mkdir -p $destination
            echo "creating directory: $destination"
        fi

        if [ -d $i ]; then
            echo "Moving $i to $destination"
            mv $i -t $destination
        fi
    done
}

findLocation Textures 
findLocation Objects
```